# How do I get the opaque version of a colour in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm building a custom control that fakes partially-rounded rectangles by drawing several rectangles on top of each other.  I want to use a colour in this control that is sourced dynamically from elsewhere -- and sometimes that colour has an alpha component (semi-transparent).  Of course, that doesn't work at all for me, since the multiple rectangles situation means that the alpha will show the rectangles layering.

Is there a function I can use to set the alpha part of a colour to full opacity and leave the rest of the colour alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access and set individual color components, like this:

```
someColor.a = 1 // set alpha to 1 for opaque
```

If you are asking about getting a pixel's value after the renderer has blended everything, there is no efficient way to do it.

If you know all colors that are blended, you can mix them manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to do that in javascript (or same in C++):

```
function makeTransparent(color, alphaPercent) {
    return color.a *= alphaPercent;
}
```

and use it as:

```
Rectangle {
    property color myColor: "#33000000"    //<-- e.g. semi-transparent black
    color: makeTransparent(mycolor, 1.2);
}
```

**Note:** my function makes color transparent in percent as `Qt.darker()` and `Qt.lighter()`